# How can I cut a variables characters to a limit? (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, variables

I would like to learn how to limit a randomized string of numbers for a program I've developed.

```
@echo off
:re
echo %RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%
goto re
```

For the sake of this, I've taken away anything unimportant.

What I would like:I want the program to randomly generate lines of numbers, have them become fitted to a certain length then echo'd to the user.

What I've Tried:I have tried to go in the direction of generating the string as a variable, "Treating it," then displaying it. The only thing I can't figure out is how to cut the variable down.

What I have now:

```
@echo off
:re
set a=%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%
<Limiting code>
echo %a%
goto re
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the ~ syntax

```
%variable:~num_to_skip%
%variable:~num_to_skip,num_to_keep%
```

Return the first 5 characters

```
set a=%a:~0,5%
```

and you can use negative numbers

Return only the last 5 characters

```
set a=%_a:~-5%
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the range of number generated as `%random%` is 0..32767, there will be a heavy bias towards 1 and 2 in any number generated of the length implied (6+ in the original post).

To overcome this bias, try

```
set "generated="
set /a length=6
:again
set /a selected=%random%
if %selected% geq 30000 goto again
set "generated=%generated%%selected:~-1%"
set /a length-=1
if %length% neq 0 goto again
```

where only the last digit is accumulated *n* times and random numbers 30000 and above are ignored, hence the range is 0..29999.

This routine may generate leading `0`s. Depending on *how* the number generated is being used, this may be significant as batch regards a numeric string with a leading `0` as an **OCTAL** number.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not help me or answer my question